# Reverse legend in geom_contour

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend, reverse

I'm struggling to find the right solution to reverse the legend, so that red is at the bottom and greens at the top. Here's a simple example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

x = seq(0.01,1,0.01)
y = seq(0.01,1,0.01)
df <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
df <- df %>% mutate(z = x*y/(1 + x))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
  geom_contour_filled(bins = 10) +
  geom_contour(bins = 20, colour = "grey") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rainbow(20))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues:

1. You're using 20 colours to describe 10 bins.
2. You're using the entire rainbow for a red-green gradient.

Suggested fix is to use the `end` and `rev` arguments of the `rainbow()` function.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

x = seq(0.01,1,0.01)
y = seq(0.01,1,0.01)
df <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
df <- df %>% mutate(z = x*y/(1 + x))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
  geom_contour_filled(bins = 10) +
  geom_contour(bins = 20, colour = "grey") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rainbow(10, end = 0.4, rev = TRUE))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Aside from that, you might want to consider to take a palette that has better visual properties than a rainbow. For example, can you really discriminate the 2nd-4th green bins visually? A close palette with better (but not perfect) properties is `viridisLite::turbo(10, begin = 0.5)`.

Comment: Thanks for the colour palette suggestions. My question, and apologies for being unclear, was not to change the colours in the plot but to present the legend with large numbers at the top and small numbers at the bottom (ie turn it upside down).

Comment: In that case, just add `guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)` to the scale.